# Why psycopg2 execute() function not escaping characters

Tags: python, database, postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

As the title indicates, I'm having problem with psycopg2 not escaping the characters passed into the execute function.

```
 query = "SELECT * FROM product_sections WHERE section_path=%s"
 cur.mogrify(query, ["Android'Test!"])
```

*OR*

```
query = "SELECT * FROM product_sections WHERE section_path=%s"
cur.mogrify(query, ("Android'Test!", ))
```

The output of `cur.mogrify()` is:

```
SELECT * FROM product_sections WHERE section_path='Android''Test!'
```

which is totally wrong. I want to **escape all those characters (', ; : ! _)**, but `psycopg2` doesn't do that for some reason.

```
ProgrammingError: syntax error at position 7
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM product_sections WHERE section_path='Android''...
```

**EDIT1:** What I want is, if the user types any of the characters: `; ' ! _` or whatever else (which may produce SQL injection), the characters should automatically be escaped. I went through the `psycopg2` docs and they said to use the `cursor.execute(query, (x,y,))` function (which, by default, should escape the characters in the strings `x`, `y`, at least, according to the docs)

**EDIT2:** Error image for better clarification.
[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It is doubling the single quote, isn't it a valid escape sequence? The exclamation point doesn't need escaping inside a string. Looks like everything is working as it should.

Comment: @PauloScardine Yes, it's doubling that, but there's the problem.

`something='x''y'` is confusing to the db

Comment: Relax, it is not - unless your database is not ANSI SQL compatible which is not the case. May be it is confusing for you, but rest assured it is not for the database.

Comment: Then, why can't psycopg2 execute the query? It's returning `ProgrammingError: syntax error at position...`

Comment: I see. Sorry for not understanding it at first, but there is a bit of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) going on here. I suggest editing the question to separate what IS your problem (syntax error) from what you thing is causing it.

Comment: @PauloScardine updated the question with the error. BTW, thanks for your responses so far

Comment: Sorry, I cant reproduce your problem (Python 2.7 and PG 9.3). The escaping performed looks just fine for me, so you should look for another source for the syntax error. Also, is this the exact query you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I cant reproduce your problem (Python 2.7 and PG 9.3). The escaping performed looks just fine for me, so you should look for another source for the syntax error.

```
>>> cur.execute(q, ["Foo';'Bar"])
>>> cur.fetchall()
[]
```

Position 7 would be right after "SELECT", are you sure you have no funky unicode character instead of a real space? I don't know Bengali but a lot of Asiatic languages have funky special space characters that look just like a regular space but causes this sort of problem.

Comment: My locale is set to English (US). There are hundreds of quries like this in our project and every query works just fine (none of them use any escaping yet). Here, position 7 means token no 7. Please see the error image I attached with the question.